# I am trying to extract specific values from a list of lists use [] and []

Tags: python

For an assignment I am given a randomly generated list of lists called by a for function.

```
for mylist in values():
```

With the first list being just numbers but all the other lists following having words in them like this.

```
[[0, 10, 12],
 [1, 'Competitor A', 'Forward'],
 [2, 'Competitor A', 'Forward'],
 [3, 'Competitor B', 'Forward'],
 [4, 'Competitor B', 'Lane Up'],]
```

I am trying to take just the first block with only digits in it by creating a new value for each of the three numbers.
So I would have

```
Value_1 = mylist[1] [0] 
Value_2 = mylist[1] [1] 
Value_3 = mylist[1] [2] here
```

Ideally I would like to seperate out the 3 values from the first Horizontal line and use them as values.

however, If I do this I run into error: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable and I am not sure what I can do to get specifically the first row. This error continues regardless of what numbers I have in either [] [] slot.

if I do something like Value1 = mylist[1] I will get 0,1,2,3,4

Do I need to create a new for loop that to seperate my values from the rest of the lists?

I am very new to Python and I am unable to find any information on this in my provided material so if this is an obviously fixable issue could someone please put me on the right path to be able to use these numbers?

Comment: ```Value_1, Value_2, Value_3 = mylist[0]```?

Comment: same error TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: so what should I do to extract the values I want?

Comment: is ```mylist``` a list of lists or is ```values()``` the list of lists?

Comment: from what I udnerstand mylist is the list of lists, this:

[[0, 10, 12],
 [1, 'Competitor A', 'Forward'],
 [2, 'Competitor A', 'Forward'],
 [3, 'Competitor B', 'Forward'],
 [4, 'Competitor B', 'Lane Up'],]

is mylist

Comment: so when you do ```print(mylist[0])``` you get ```[0, 10, 12]```?

Comment: when I do print(mylist[0]) I get 0, 1, 2,3 ,4

it reads the values vertically

Comment: You're doing that in the for loop? I think ```values()``` is the list of lists so ```Value_1, Value_2, Value_3 = values()[0]``` should give you what you want

Comment: Ok that sort of did it except when I put in values() it calls the function again and as the function generates a random data set it pulls these values I needed from a new generated list of values. I think I can do something from here but again if there is an obvious solution please let me know, thank you.

Comment: just do ```a = values()``` and then use ```a``` everywhere to avoid generating new values

Comment: can you give me an example of this?

Comment: I just gave you an example?

Comment: Sorry, I think you're saying that a = all three of the values, I think it would have the same effect if I do something like a= value1, b=value2 and c= value3, I did that and it generates new datasets for each one

Comment: so you have a function ```values``` that returns a list of lists with random data. If you only want one set of random data you don't want to call ```values()``` again, so you store it's output in a variable ```a``` by doing ```a=values()```. You can then access the first list with ```a[0]``` and store these values in three new variables with ```Value_1, Value_2, Value_3 = a[0]```

Comment: I think I have a seperate deeper lying issue with how I have structured my code, your initial answer is basically what I was looking for but I have a different question I will need to make a new topic for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`when I do print(mylist[0]) I get 0, 1, 2,3 ,4 it reads the values vertically` 
If above is the case and you just want the first 3 elements from the horizontal
Here's what you can do

```
n1 = mylist[0][0]
n2 = mylist[1][0]
n3 = mylist[2][0]
```

Comment: 'Ideally I would like to seperate out the 3 values from the first Horizontal line and use them as values.'

Comment: That's what I did, n1,n2, n3 has them

Comment: but it's the first value from each list, not the values from the first list

Comment: You should print out your values() first and show here

Comment: they want to get ```n1=0```, ```n2=10```, ```n3=12```

Comment: if he shows the entire values() It could be easier

Comment: they have shown all you need, you have ```n1=0```, ```n2=1```, ```n3=2``` (the first elements from each list) when they want ```n1=0```, ```n2=10```, ```n3=12``` the elements from the first list

Comment: I was trying to make a new question for this but my issue comes from how I call the provided code to create a list. I couldn't figure out how to call what they put in my template and so I essentially skip what they gave given and generate my own list. Seperating the list out like this replecates it for each step and so I think now I must stop using the function they use and instead figure out what I am supposed to reference in my for loops. I understand I am speaking like I know nothing and that's because I do but these responses have helped clarify the issue I was having.

Comment: What they have given me extracts code from another file that generates the list and what I did was take data_set from this incoming block (I will post as an answer to my question)  and use that in my code which is what is generating the new lists each time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `values()` returns following list:

```
[[0, 10, 12],
 [1, 'Competitor A', 'Forward'],
 [2, 'Competitor A', 'Forward'],
 [3, 'Competitor B', 'Forward'],
 [4, 'Competitor B', 'Lane Up']]
```

Try following to get the first rows values of the return. Remove the for loop if its not needed:

```
myListofLists = values()
Value_1 = myListofLists[0][0]
Value_2 = myListofLists[0][1]
Value_3 = myListofLists[0][2]
```

**Explanation to your question**

The for loop iterates through every element of the returned list:

simply:

```
for myList in values():
    print(myList)
```

gives following output:

```
[0, 10, 12]
[1, 'Competitor A', 'Forward']
[2, 'Competitor A', 'Forward']
[3, 'Competitor B', 'Forward']
[4, 'Competitor B', 'Lane Up']
```

Taking the [0] element of my List (`print(myList[0])`) outputs:

```
0 # for loop first time [0, ...
1 # for loop second time [1, ...
2 # ...
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

For an assignment I have been given this code that pulls data from 2 seperate files. one of them creates a drawing template for use with the turtle module (that file is not important here) and the other creates a randomly generated list of instructions that I must program the turtle to follow.

This is their code for generating the list, it spits out a list of instructions that I am not sure of how to access.

```
    if isfile('data_visualisation_configuration.py'):
    print('\nConfiguration module found ...\n')
    from data_visualisation_configuration import *
else:
    print("\nCannot find file 'data_visualisation_configuration.py', aborting!\n")
    abort()

# Define the function for generating data sets, using the
# imported raw data generation function if available, but
# otherwise creating a dummy function that just returns an
# empty list
if isfile('data_visualisation_data_source.py'):
    print('Data generation module found ...\n')
    from data_visualisation_data_source import raw_data
    def data_set(new_seed = randint(0, 99999)):
        print('Using random number seed', new_seed, '...\n')
        seed(new_seed) # set the seed
        return raw_data() # return the random data set
else:
    print('No data generation module available ...\n')
    def data_set(dummy_parameter = None):
        return []
```

I can see that data_set() is the function they are using to generate their list and if I call upon it myself I am able to generate my own lists for use, the issue is that as I am calling the function, it generates a new dataset each time it is referenced in a loop and floods the shell with datasets. I have my instructions all sorted but calling their dataset function was the only way I could figure out to acces their list, if not this way then what am I supposed to call on? I just need to know what function I am supposed to call in my instructions (that are not included) to prevent my code from generating multiple data sets and only use the one provided by their block of code. (raw_data() has the same issue)

Comment: I've never used this website before so I apologize for my butchering of it but I will post this as a seperate question in 90~ minutes if this is bannable or whatever haha

Comment: You can edit the original question if you want to add more information. Please delete this answer.